# Convert Func<DerivedType, Object> to Func<BaseType, Object>

Tags: c#, delegates

What is the best way to convert from a delegate that takes a first parameter of a derived type into one that receives a base type?
What I mean is:

```
Func<DerivedType, Object> original = ...;
Func<BaseType, Object> converted = Something(original);
```

Casts, of course, do not work, since these are actually two different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to pass a base type to a method that takes a derived type, you need to add a cast. If you know that all calls to `converted` would be passing `DerivedType`, you could make a straightforward wrapper, like this:

```
Func<BaseType,Object> converted = b => original((DerivedType)b);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/pyQIFP)