# Convert Func<T, object> to Func<FrameworkElement, object>

Tags: c#, generics

I have a 2 classes :

```
class Model
{
    //...
    public Func<FrameworkElement , object> Property { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

and

```
class Other
{
    public void MyMethod<T>(Type type, Func<T, object> selector) where T : FrameworkElement
    {
        this.MyList.Add(new Model() { Property = selector  });
    }    
}
```

I have an error : `Impossible to convert Func<T,object> to Func<FrameworkElement,object>`

when I try :

```
var tmp = selector as Func<FrameworkElement, object>
```

the value of tmp is `null`.

Why I use a method signature  like this ?
Because the method will be called, and I can't predict what is the framework element, for exemple :

```
myVar.MyMethod<TextBox>(t=>t.Text) ;
```

or

```
myVar.MyMethod<Label>(t=>t.Content) ;
```

Comment: What is the point of being generic here, and why wouldn't you just specify `FrameworkElement` as the parameter type instead of using constraints?

Comment: I'll call the method from another class :
myVar.MyMethod<TextBox>(t=>t.Text) ;
or
myVar.MyMethod<Label>(t=>t.Content) ;
I can't predict what other developers will use as a FrameworkElement

Comment: Can you not change MyMethod to: MyMethod(Type type, Func<FrameworkElement, object> selector) and use polymorphism

Comment: * edited comment as accidentally submitted it before I had finished

Comment: If you must have it as a generic, you could always try a wrapper lambda like: `Func<FrameworkElement, object> SelectorWrapper = f => selector((T)f);` and use that instead.

Comment: You cannot assign a `Func<T, object>` to a `Func<FrameworkElement, object>` A function that works on a `TextBox` may not work on just any `FrameworkElement`. Not every `FrameworkElement` has a `Text` property. (The other way around *does* work)

Comment: I think this topic can help you
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410342/convert-funcderivedtype-object-to-funcbasetype-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410342/convert-funcderivedtype-object-to-funcbasetype-object)

Comment: @Dennis_E, Exactly, not every FrameworkElement has a Text property, that's why I'm using generics, so the caller can pass the property as a parameter.

Comment: @DotNeter Model has a `Func<FrameworkElement, object>` and `t => t.Text` is not a `Func<FrameworkElement, object>`. It is "only" a `Func<TextBox, object>`. Contravariance works "the other way around"

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Func< T, TResult>, have covariant return types and contravariant
>   parameter types.

This means that the T parameter can be a "less derived class".

So if you do the following it works:

```
public class MyFrameworkElement { }
public class MyTextBox : MyFrameworkElement { }

class Program 
{    
        public static Object MyMethod(MyFrameworkElement b) 
        {
            return new Object();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {

            Func<MyFrameworkElement, Object> f1 = MyMethod;
            Func<MyTextBox, Object> f2 = f1;
       }
}
```

As you see, you can assign a Func< MyFrameworkElement, Object> to a Func< MyTextBox, Object>, since the first parameter is contravariant (you can assign a "less derived type" in this case MyFrameworkElement to MyTextBox).

Like I said the type parameter is contravariant and not covariant, so it does not work the other way around!

Like this:

```
class Program 
{    
    public static Object MyMethod2(MyTextBox b) 
    {
            return new Object();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        Func<MyTextBox, Object> f3 = MyMethod2;

        //This does not compile, and with cast you cannot make this work either.
        Func<MyFrameworkElement, Object> f4 = f3;  // as Func<MyFrameworkElement, Object>; <- does not help
    }
}
```

And this makes sense, since MyMethod2 has a MyTextBox parameter, and f4 would point to a MyFrameworkElement. MyTextBox could have a Text property which you could access in MyMethod2, but with f4 you would pass a MyFrameworkElement, which do not have that property.

Unfortunately what you want to do is this second case.